# Can't call a method to return a VIEW in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know why I can't return a view in a different method, it's very simple:
In **routes.php** I have:

```
Route::get('/viewer', 'ViewerController@index');
```

And this works, in **ViewerController.php**:

```
public function index()
{
   return view('viewer'); 
}
```

However this doesn't work:

```
public function index()
{
   $this->generalViewer(); 
}

public function generalViewer()
{
   return view('viewer');
}
```

I get no error, simply nothing is returned.
why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is:

```
public function index()
{
   // Return what `generalViewer()` returns
   return $this->generalViewer(); 
}
```